# OCR Scanning with specific font

Tags: java, android, fonts, ocr, scanning

I am implementing an OCR scanning library for Android App which scans not just numbers but also scan those number with specific fonts which I have defined manually somewhere in library.

I am trying to implement "TESSERACT" library but didn't found font specific scanning implementation. I am using following code to scan OCR not a particular font. My implementation is given below:

```
 private void processImage(Bitmap bMap, String imagePath) {
        try {
            datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tesseract/";
            checkFile(new File(datapath + "tessdata/"));
            TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
            baseApi.init(datapath, "eng");
            baseApi.setImage(bMap);
            String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
            baseApi.end();
            Log.e("log_tag", "onActivityResult recognizedText : " + recognizedText);
            Fragment myFragment = getActiveFragment();
            if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible() && myFragment instanceof ScanPrescriptionFragment7c) {
                ((ScanPrescriptionFragment7c) myFragment).displaySelectedImage(recognizedText, imagePath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Is there any way i can achieve font independent OCR implementation or atleast can provide a custom font to scan for during initialization of OCR? 
Thanks!

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.

Comment: @GabeSechan I think this not off topic

Comment: @JigneshAnsodariya He's asking for a library to do something.  That is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand exactly why do you need to specify a font to recognize the characters, do you want to scan different languages or something like that?

I have been developing an Android app with OCR using Tesseract and I wrote down my conclusions and included an example in [this post](https://solidgeargroup.com/ocr-on-android), have a look at it, might be useful to solve your case.